# lambda is replace with λ in racket-mode emacs

Tags: emacs, racket

For example: `(define f (lambda (x) (* x 2)))` when I wrote `lambda` and pressed space, the word "lambda" is replaced with λ. How can I disable this replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this

`M-x global-prettify-symbols-mode`

to disable it for the current session. Or put this in your `init.el`

`(global-prettify-symbols-mode -1)`

to disable it completely. It will kill the entire prettifying behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657870/4905506) if you need finer grain control.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case, but I figured out what causes that to happen. I simply deleted this line `(add-hook 'racket-mode-hook      #'racket-unicode-input-method-enable)` in `.emacs`.

Comment: OP: Please consider posting your comment here as an answer. You can accept your own answer. That will remove the question from the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what causes that to happen. I simply deleted this line `(add-hook 'racket-mode-hook #'racket-unicode-input-method-enable)` in `.emacs`.